# Undefined method .split for Nil class Ruby

Tags: ruby

Undefined method for nil:Nilclass

In a class, a method counts the number of words in a paragraph.An error occurs when a method is called(1). I can’t understand how to pass the argument methods using send.

If I remove the class and put the def calc_1(paragraph) method into the loop, then everything works, I start calling the select method. It turns out he does not see my books variable with text, when there is a class.

```
@books = "You can use this knowledge to create small tools that might help."

class Filecalculation

    def select
        loop do
            puts "# Will we search : сounting words in text File(1)".cyan
            print "\n>>>>>> "

            input = gets.chomp
            search_method = "calc_#{input}".to_sym
            if (respond_to?(search_method))
                contents = send(search_method, @books)
            end 
       end 
    end  

    def calc_1 paragraph            
        word_count = paragraph.split.length 
        puts "#{word_count} words"   
    end
end

Filecalculation.new.select
```

Comment: Try `search_method = "calc_#{input}".to_sym` It needs to be a symbol

Comment: You'll need to do a little work to debug this code and make sure each operation is producing the expected results. Try breaking this up into smaller pieces, or introducing `p` or `pp` debugging tests.

Comment: Ok try to break the code.

Comment: Here's an easier way: `@books.strip.squeeze(' ').count(' ') + 1 #=> 12`. [String#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-strip) removes any errant white space before the first word and after the last word. [String#squeeze](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) replaces any string of spaces with a single space, ensuring there to be exactly one space between successive words.  [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-count) counts spaces, which is one less than the number of words. This counts hyphenated words as one word.

Comment: A second way to do this without creating an array of words is to use  [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a single argument and no block, the argument being a regular expression, and [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count): `@books.gsub(/\w+/).count #=> 12`. `\w` matches any *word* character: letters, digits and the underscore.

Comment: Thanks, I took the first method, in the code below I introduced.               
 word_count = paragraph.strip.squeeze(' ').count(' ') + 1  
 puts "#{word_count} words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If replaced by search_method = "calc_#{input}".to_sym also works.

Helped add def initialize @books end.

Instead of contents = send (search_method, @books) you can use send (search_method, @books).

```
require "colorize"

class Filecalculation

    def initialize
        @books = "You can use this knowledge to create small tools that might help you."
    end

    def calc_1 paragraph            
        word_count = paragraph.strip.squeeze(' ').count(' ') + 1  
        puts "#{word_count} words"   
    end

    def select

        loop do
            puts "# Will we search : Calculation_lines paragraph(1)".cyan
            print "\n>>>>>> ".yellow
            input = gets.chomp
            search_method = "calc_#{input}" #.to_sym

            if (respond_to?(search_method))
                contents = send(search_method, @books)
            else
                puts "exit "
                exit
            end
       end 
    end
end

Filecalculation.new.select
```